# Managing Windows Event Logs in XML format

Tags: xml, windows, event-log

I am receiving event log files as XML.  Are there any tools (preferably free) to do one of the following:

- Convert the XML to EVTX so I can view each entry
- Allow me to open the XML file to view each entry in a GUI rather than a block of XML